# The uploaded images are only full-size (original)

Tags: images

Usually uploaded to the library pictures are divided into 4 sizes: full, large, medium, and thumbnail. But as it happens, the uploaded images are only full-size (original).

It is necessary to divide the already uploaded images by size, how to do it? And how to make the images are automatically loaded and divided into 4 sizes?

Comment: it sounds like your server has no image resizing PHP extensions such as GD or Imagick, you should check the site health page in your Admin area which highlights this. The other possibility is your uploaded images full size is massive and the server can't resize them down in time, e.g. if you were uploading 100 Megapixel raw photos, but it's more likely to be the former. WP is supposed to do all the resizing for you if it can. If you're missing PHP extensions you'll need to have them installed by contacting your host or adding the missing packages if you did it yourself

Comment: From WordPress 5.3, it downscale any image that exceed 2560px width. And, creates resized images which are defined by `add_image_size` plus the default ones. To be able to do that, the server needs to have image processing libraries (mainly GD/Imagick) (php extensions installed). Check your extensions using a `phpinfo()` lookup.